# Graphics card doesn't work, not detected(?), on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card

I have a problem with a graphics card. I use Linux [Elementary OS]. I have a Lenovo Z50-75 laptop. I want to install drivers for my graphics card, but I can't. Model graphics card is AMD R7 m260dx. When I ran `lspci` I got this information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6/R7 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1425
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

You see this graphics card isn't there.

What should I do?

Ok, when I wrote cat /proc/cpuinfo I got this:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1300.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]
```

What I should to do now?

Comment: elementaryOS has its own StackExchange site: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's actually detected. See the third line from the bottom: `Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230] (rev ff)`.

Comment: Also the second line from the top: `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6/R7 Graphics]`. What CPU is in the laptop? Check the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: I got this  model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I wrote **cat /proc/cpuinfo** I got this

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 48
model name  : AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6003106
cpu MHz     : 1300.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 4192.18
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13]
```

What I should to do now?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for adding the information. But please use the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1232247/edit) link to paste the relevant part into your own question. As it is it is showing up as an answer.